# Matching folder name using bash

Tags: bash, glob

I have this piece of code to match the folder name:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in teste/* 
do 
    if [ "$dir" = 1 ]; then 
        echo "folder 1"; 
    fi
    if [ "$dir" = 2 ]; then
        echo "folder 2";
    fi
done
```

And I have a directory called **teste/1/** and **teste/2/**
After running the script above, my output is nothing! There are no errors...

Do you know how to solve it? I don't know why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `dir` does not contain `1` or `2` but `teste/1` or `teste/2`.

Use, e.g.:

```
if [ "$dir" = "teste/1" ]; then
```