# Matching directory names and taking action with array

Tags: bash, shell, glob

Can you help me?

I want create a dynamic folder match, and if the folder name match an item in array, then an output will be triggered according the folder name.
Here is an example.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=("banana"=>"yellow", "apple"=>"red", "watermelon"=>"green")
for dir in fruits/* 
do 
    if [ "$dir" = "{banana, apple or watermelon}" ]; then 
        echo "The color of the fruit is: {fruit-color}"
    fi
done
```

But I have no idea about how can I start, I only did this simple code above to you understand. Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: To `for dir in fruits/* ` see this question: [Matching folder name using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56821197/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Associative arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays-1) are created this way:

```
declare -A fruit
fruit=( ["banana"]="yellow" ["apple"]="red" ["watermelon"]="green" )
```

Your conditional can be implemented as a [`case` statement](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29):

```
case "$dir" in
    banana|apple|watermelon)
        echo "The color of the fruit is: ${fruit[$dir]}"
        ;;
    *)
        break
esac
```

[Matching the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3685970/96588) is a bit clunky but can be done:

```
for key in "${!fruit[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$dir" = "$key" ]]
    then
        echo "The color of the fruit is: ${fruit[$key]}"
    fi
done
```

Running the resulting script through [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a good idea, and [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/) is a great place to learn Bash.

Comment: Are there no ways to avoid repeating items names? For example, `banana` exists in array and on case condition. I want make it more simple like: `if folder name == array item`. Because I have a lot of folders. Thank you!

Comment: [Checking whether an array contains an item in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3685970/96588) is clunky compared to modern languages. For this reason I never recommend Bash for anything more than simple scripts.

Comment: The puzzle pieces put together: `declare -A A; A=( ["banana"]="yellow" ["apple"]="red" ["watermelon"]="green" ); for dir in fruit/*; do dir=$(basename "$dir"); for key in "${!A[@]}"; do if [[ "$dir" == "$key" ]]; then echo "The color of fruit $key is: ${A[$key]}"; fi; done; done`